# Remove a comma in a matrix in r

Tags: r, gsub

This problem to me is harder than it might sound. I imported a GML file. I now have all of my rows with numbers followed by a `,`. I can't figure out how to remove and make numeric.  I have tried as.numeric and gsub, but when I do my adjacency matrix I get this output:

```
  [1,] . 1 . . 1 . . . . 1 . . . . . . 1 . . . . . . 1 . . . . . . . . . 1 . 1 . . . ......
  [2,] 1 . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . 1 . 1 . . . . . 1 . . . 1 . ......
```

I need the numbers in the [1,] to be a real number so I can attempt a loop that I will come back later for help on!

This code doesn't work:

```
games[0] <- as.numeric(gsub("[^[:digit:]]","",games[0]))
```

I get this error:

```
Error in `[<-.igraph`(`*tmp*`, 0, value = numeric(0)) : 
  Logical or numeric value must be of length 1
```

Here is the code I have:

```
library(igraph)
games <- read.graph("football.gml", format="gml")
```

and I eventually need to be able to look this algorithm:

```
get.shortest.paths(games, 1, 155,  weights = NULL ,output=c("vpath", "epath", "both"))
```

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example.

Answer (score 0):

[1,] is a row with multiple values (one for each column), not a single string. gsub returns an error because it is only designed for use on a single string. You need to loop over each value in the n x k matrix (or use an apply function to do this) and apply the gsub function to each individual value. Also not sure why you are replacing `"[^[:digit:]]"`. Keep in mind this will substitute out the literal string `"[^[:digit:]]"` , not whatever this references in R. Here is an example in a loop:

```
for (i in 1:nrow(data)){
    for (j in 1:ncol(data)){
        data[i,j] <- gsub(".", "", data[i,j])
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could do something creative like this:

```
read.table(text='1 2 3 4 ,
5 6 7 8 ,
9 1 2 3 ,', sep=' ', na.strings=',')
```

And then drop the last column.

Comment: I should note that I don't know what a GML file is, so not sure if you can import with `read.table`...